# Update row based on order of parameter

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I'm trying to add a field to a created feature class, then create a key based on whether the AccountNo is equal to the imputed Feature1 through 6. For example, if Feature1 is equal to the AccountNo when it goes through the list of polygons, it will set the feature class in the created field to 1, if Feature2 is equal to the Account No, it will set it to 2, and so on. My code only has one update query now, but I'd like it to run through each "Feature". Is this doable using this technique?

```
import arcpy

FClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Feature1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Feature2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
Feature3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
Feature4 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
Feature5 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
Feature6 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)

relateFieldsList = ["StrNum", "Street", "StrSuf", "StrUnit", "AccountNo"]

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Comps"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Comp_Num", "TEXT", field_length = 10)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Comp_Num") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if "AccountNo" == Feature1:
                row[0] = 1
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The field name (`"AccountNo"`) needs to be in your cursor field inputs. Something like this:

```
 for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Comps"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Comp_Num", "TEXT", field_length = 10)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["AccountNo", "Comp_Num"]) as cursor:
        for acc, comp in cursor:
            if acc == Feature1:
                comp = 1
            if acc == Feature2:
                comp = 2
            if acc == Feature3:
                comp = 3
            if acc == Feature4:
                comp = 4
            if acc == Feature5:
                comp = 5
            if acc == Feature6:
                comp = 6
            row = (acc, comp)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this seemed to delete the rows entirely. Will this still work if not every Feature has an input?

Answer (score 0):

Using Emil's code I was able to make it work with some alterations. I needed to calculate the field first, then it gave the cursor something to compare it to. Here's the result

```
import arcpy

FClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Feature1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Feature2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
Feature3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
Feature4 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
Feature5 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
Feature6 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)

relateFC1 = r"Comps"

for df in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Comps"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(df, "Comp_Num", "TEXT", field_length= 10)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(df, "Comp_Num", "AccountNo")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(relateFC1, ["AccountNo", "Comp_Num"]) as cursor:
    for acc, comp in cursor:
        if acc == Feature1:
            comp = 1
        if acc == Feature2:
            comp = 2
        if acc == Feature3:
            comp = 3
        if acc == Feature4:
            comp = 4
        if acc == Feature5:
            comp = 5
        if acc == Feature6:
            comp = 6
        row = (acc, comp)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```